# SQL JOIN query issue provides inaccurate return

Tags: mysql, sql

I have spend hours searching for this specific issue on the site though many are close not address it completely.  Please link it if it exists and I will happily take down this question.

I have two tables **wb_states** and **wb_cities** you can see by the keys:

`composite state_code+country_code` & `city_id` are distinctive for their respective tables.

[image]

OBJECTIVE: run a JOIN query to pull in the `state_name` from the wb_states table (in place of the state_code)

I always get the ***sql_mode=only_full_group_by*** ERROR unless I use the following

```sql
SELECT ANY_VALUE(c.city_id) as id, 
       ANY_VALUE(c.city_ascii) as ci,
       ANY_VALUE(s.state_name_ascii) as ps, 
       ANY_VALUE(c.country_code) as co
       FROM wb_cities AS c
       JOIN wb_states AS s ON
       s.state_code=c.state_code
       WHERE c.city_ascii like  'aa%' GROUP BY id ORDER BY co,ps,ci ASC
```

Of course the query works but the moment we employ ANY_VALUE it fails.

Unique id `2959927` - city of `Aalen` belongs to only one province `Baden-Wurttemberg`.  How do you construct this query?  Thank you.

[image]

```sql
CREATE TABLE `wb_cities` (
  `city_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `city_name` varchar(65) DEFAULT NULL,
  `city_ascii` varchar(65) DEFAULT NULL,
  `state_code` varchar(55) DEFAULT NULL,
  `state_name_ascii` varchar(45) DEFAULT NULL,
  `country_code` varchar(45) DEFAULT NULL,
  `country_full` varchar(55) DEFAULT NULL,
  `lat` varchar(45) DEFAULT NULL,
  `lon` varchar(45) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`city_id`)
)

CREATE TABLE `wb_states` (
  `id` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `state_code` varchar(10) NOT NULL,
  `state_name` varchar(45) DEFAULT NULL,
  `state_name_ascii` varchar(45) DEFAULT NULL,
  `country_code` varchar(45) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`state_code`,`country_code`)
)

INSERT INTO `wb_cities` VALUES (14256,'Āzādshahr','Azadshahr','09','Hamadan','IR','Iran','34.79049','48.57011'),(18918,'Protaras','Protaras','01','Famagusta','CY','Cyprus','35.0125','34.05833'),(23814,'Kahrīz','Kahriz','13','Kermanshah','IR','Iran','34.3838','47.0553'),(24851,'Nūrābād','Nurabad','23','Lorestan','IR','Iran','34.0734','47.9725'),(32723,'Īstgāh-e Rāh Āhan-e Garmsār','Istgah-e Rah Ahan-e Garmsar','25','Semnan','IR','Iran','35.23455','52.30942'),(32767,'Qarchak','Qarchak','26','Tehran','IR','Iran','35.42867','51.57544'),(32909,'Shahre Jadide Andisheh','Shahre Jadide Andisheh','26','Tehran','IR','Iran','35.6803','51.0193'),(41210,'Khorramdarreh','Khorramdarreh','36','Zanjan Province','IR','Iran','36.20898','49.19152'),(50672,'Wanlaweyn','Wanlaweyn','14','Shabeellaha Hoose','SO','Somalia','2.6185','44.8938'),(52867,'Qoryooley','Qoryooley','14','Shabeellaha Hoose','SO','Somalia','1.78784','44.52999');

INSERT INTO `wb_states` VALUES (29,'00','Armenia','Armenia','AM'),(11,'00','Aruba','Aruba','AW'),(15,'00','Bosnia and Herzegovina','Bosnia and Herzegovina','BA'),(31,'00','Botswana','Botswana','BW'),(7,'00','Belarus','Belarus','BY'),(23,'00','Cook Islands','Cook Islands','CK'),(39,'00','Christmas Island','Christmas Island','CX'),(4,'00','Czech Republic','Czech Republic','CZ'),(17,'00','Western Sahara','Western Sahara','EH'),(10,'00','Falkland Islands (Islas Malvinas)','Falkland Islands (Islas Malvinas)','FK'),(26,'00','Abkhazia','Abkhazia','GE'),(27,'00','Ghana','Ghana','GH'),(37,'00','Gibraltar','Gibraltar','GI'),(3,'00','Equatorial Guinea','Equatorial Guinea','GQ'),(16,'00','South Georgia and The South Sandwich Islands','South Georgia and The South Sandwich Islands','GS'),(28,'00','Hong Kong','Hong Kong','HK'),(6,'00','Indonesia','Indonesia','ID'),(8,'00','Ireland','Ireland','IE'),(32,'00','Kyrgyzstan','Kyrgyzstan','KG'),(36,'00','Comoros','Comoros','KM'),(34,'00','Muḩāfaz̧atalWafrah','MuhafazatalWafrah','KW'),(19,'00','Zhezqazghan Oblysy','Zhezqazghan Oblysy','KZ'),(21,'00','Lithuania','Lithuania','LT'),(40,'00','Monaco','Monaco','MC'),(13,'00','Montenegro','Montenegro','ME'),(9,'00','Mali','Mali','ML'),(5,'00','Macedonia','Macedonia','MO'),(35,'00','Mauritius','Mauritius','MU'),(25,'00','Malaysia','Malaysia','MY'),(41,'00','Norfolk Island','Norfolk Island','NF'),(30,'00','Bāgmatī Zone','Bagmati Zone','NP'),(2,'00','Niue','Niue','NU'),(14,'00','Panama','Panama','PA'),(22,'00','Philippines','Philippines','PH'),(42,'00','Palestine','Palestine','PS'),(43,'00','Serbia','Serbia','RS'),(24,'00','Swaziland','Swaziland','SZ'),(20,'00','Turks and Caicos Islands','Turks and Caicos Islands','TC'),(33,'00','Turkmenistan','Turkmenistan','TM'),(38,'00','Turkey','Turkey','TR'),(12,'00','British Virgin Islands','British Virgin Islands','VG'),(18,'00','Zimbabwe','Zimbabwe','ZW'),(164,'01','Abū Z̧aby','Abu Zaby','AE'),(90,'01','Badakhshan','Badakhshan','AF'),(112,'01','Barbuda','Barbuda','AG'),(118,'01','Aragatsotn','Aragatsotn','AM'),(124,'01','Benguela','Benguela','AO'),(45,'01','Buenos Aires','Buenos Aires','AR'),(146,'01','Burgenland','Burgenland','AT');
```

Comment: The return is fine.  Your understanding is wrong.  I would suggest that you ask a new question with sample data and desired results,

Comment: I acknowledge your remark `the return is fine` - no offence intended.  My point was `how does one create the query`.  Data sample is posted thank you.

Comment: Learning a proper `GROUP BY` would be a good start.

Comment: @Nelles . . . This question is about why a supposedly incorrect query does not work.  I would suggest that you ask a NEW question.  Focus on sample data, desired results, and an explanation of what you want to accomplish.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You join `wb_cities` to `wb_states` only on `state_code` but you should also use `country_code`, because `state_code` is not unique in `wb_states`.
Also I don't see any reason for aggregation. You need only a join of the tables:

```
SELECT c.city_id id, 
       c.city_ascii ci,
       s.state_name_ascii ps, 
       c.country_code co
FROM wb_cities AS c JOIN wb_states AS s 
ON s.state_code=c.state_code AND s.country_code = c.country_code
WHERE c.city_ascii like  'aa%' 
ORDER BY co, ps, ci
```

Comment: This is brilliant I did not read the edited version!  It works on my original table config.  I want to edit the post with my screen capture but currently `Suggested edit queue is full` for me.

Answer (score 1):

Your data model is broken.  Here are two definitions of `state_code`:

```
`state_code` varchar(55) 
`state_code` varchar(10)
```

And yet this is part of an undeclared foreign key relationship.

I think this is the root problem:

```
PRIMARY KEY (`state_code`, `country_code`)
```

Presumably, the `ID` is unique, so you should have:

```
CREATE TABLE `wb_states` (
  `state_id` int(11) DEFAULT PRIMARY KEY,
  `state_code` varchar(10) NOT NULL,
  `state_name` varchar(45) DEFAULT NULL,
  `state_name_ascii` varchar(45) DEFAULT NULL,
  `country_code` varchar(45) NOT NULL,
  `country_full` varchar(55) DEFAULT NULL,
  UNIQUE (`state_code`,`country_code`)
);
```

Then, your `wb_cities` table can be appropriately defined as:

```
CREATE TABLE `wb_cities` (
  `city_id` int(11) NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
  `city_name` varchar(65) DEFAULT NULL,
  `city_ascii` varchar(65) DEFAULT NULL,
  `state_id` int DEFAULT NULL,
  `lat` varchar(45) DEFAULT NULL,
  `lon` varchar(45) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`city_id`),
  FOREIGN KEY (state_id) REFERENCES wb_states(state_id)
);
```

You should probably have a "countries" table as well, but at least the country can go in the "states" table rather than the "cities" table.

Then, the "state" information can be looked up using the `state_id`.

After you have fixed the data model, you can think about fixing the query.

Comment: Thank you for this thoughtful response @Gordon Linoff - I am investing time into more complex SQL queries with relational databases right now - this is a big help.

Comment: @Nelles The title of your question is *..using ANY_VALUE provides inaccurate return...* Is this the answer to the question that you posted?

Comment: In a round about way it was because it indicated that I was asking the wrong question.

Comment: So after the changes you made to the tables (if you made any) did the query return correct results?

Comment: I was given two CSV files and I had inaccurately set PRIMARY KEY (`state_code`, `country_code`).  After reconstructing the tables / keys it makes sense.  I am primarily a front end programmer so I can go months with out ever needing more than basic SQL.  Please excuse me if you find my question to be stupid.  I am trying to be thoughtful and heavily researched before posting question.

Comment: It can be intimidating on here when you get downvoted quickly even with sincere question and many hours of doing leg work in advance.  One of the comments above basically says the question is stupid so I don't know.

Comment: @Nelles . . . I'm disappointed you unaccepted this answer, which seemed to be the more helpful to you.

Comment: @Gordon Linoff many participants ask thoughtless question here or are looking for `shortcuts` and `quick fixes`.  I did not do that and yet have taken a lot of flack for the post. The @forpas solution addressed the objective of my native table structure and was validation that my post was not obscene.  I have taken a loss on points here but will leave it up in the hopes that it can save someone else time and provide learning.  Sorry that you are disappointed.